# Drupal - Restricted Content Access to show Login Page for Annoymous Users

Tags: drupal-7

As the title states, I'm trying to locate a module which will allow me to define a page as restricted to Authenticated users but one which will show or redirect to the login page for Annoymous Users, some of the modules I have found only do the first part, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your description is a little bit misleading but as the title states I think you can use the [Redirect 403 to User Login Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/r4032login) to have this functionality.